# What is the best way to internally call an AWS Lambda function within another Lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Seems a little inefficient the way it currently is:

```
response.body = {
   user: await userService(userID) // calls a user service to get info on user
   friends: await friendsService(userID) // calls a friends service to get info on friends for 
}
```

Let's say the userService and friendsService are configured on different API Gateway endpoints.

Then wouldn't that make the network request take longer than if I were to just package my entire backend into one zip file that's uploaded to AWS Lambda.

Seems like this is very inefficient.

Is there a way to call other lambdas without having to make a network request? I understand putting the lambdas/gateway in the same VPC as the main Gateway endpoint exposed to the internet, but this is expensive?

Anyway to do this more efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

You can call a Lambda function by using the AWS SDK (a LambdaClient object). So, for example assume you wrote two Lambda functions - funA and funB.

Next assume:

- you want to call funB from funA
- you wrote your Lambda function by using the Lambda Java runtime

You can use the Lambda Java API to invoke funB. There is no need to wrap either one in Restful call using API Gateway. You can use the AWS SDK. Here is the Java API example that shows you how to invoke a Lambda function:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/javav2/example_code/lambda/src/main/java/com/example/lambda/LambdaInvoke.java

Answer (score 0):

@smac2020 writes in the answer about using SDK, that is of course a network call too. It just skips api gateway and calls directly AWS api.

I think the key point about Lambda is if it scales well. Let you try to thing about the algorithms in a different way. For example you can create a pipeline where in each step your "state object" is enriched with additional data. You can use step function or SQS and send the requests in between the steps or you can make the client responsible to manage the data. You should try to avoid one function waiting for another function. You are then paying two lambdas running - the caller and the called one.

If you are thinking "but microservices..." - look at the design of the AWS API itself. You do not need output of one service as an input to another one. It needs some time to adapt and to look at problems from different perspectives. In your case I would consider if the user list can for example live in the user object and the calls can be merged (look at some no-sql database design principles).